# Can a Tomcat server use a different JVM than Visual Studio Code Java Extension

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code, jvm

when I try to debug an Java web application on Tomcat with Visual Studio Code I found no way to set the JVM the Tomcat server should use. This is possible in Eclipse (Runtime environment). Can this be configured in Visual Code?

Things I tried:

Visual Code needs a Java 11+ VM to support Java projects, while the projects itself might use another JVM to run. I'm using the Tomcat server extension with the following java settings:

```
{
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Java\\jdk-8.0.222",
            "default":  true
          },
          {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "C:\\Java\\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot",
            "sources" : "C:\\Java\\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot\\lib\\src.zip",
            "javadoc" : "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api",
            "default":  false
           }
    ],
    "java.home": "C:\\Java\\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot"
}
```

While JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Java\jdk-8.0.222, the Visual Code Java extension doesn't start, when I change change java.home to the Java 8 JVM (This was expected).
Now, when I startup Tomcat from within Visual Code the java.home JVM is always used.

Question: Is there a way to configure Tomcat to use another JVM when started from Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

Java Extension Pack need jdk11 or rencent version to launch the language server, so JDK8 won't start the extension.

Set JDK11 as `java.home` to support extensions and JDK8 for `java.runtime` is totally achiveable. Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Configure Java Runtime**: choose the existed jdk8 and don't forget to **reload window to make this setting effective**:

[image]

After reloading the window, run the java file again, you'll find it's using jdk configured by java.runtime:

[image]

**[EDIT]**
Turn to the foloder tomcat\bin, add the following code at the start of `setclasspath.bat`:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk-8.0.222
set JRE_HOME=\path\to\jre8
```

After modifying the setclasspath file, Tomcat will start with the set JDK

Comment: Sorry, this answer doesn't make the point. This is about the Tomcat Server Visual Code extension and not a plain Java program. The Tomcat server acts as a container for Java Web Applications (Servlets...) and uses his own JVM. Therefore my question....

Comment: @jprusch. Sorry for my misunderstanding to your question. About set specific jdk to tomcat, you should make some changes to tomcat\setclasspath.bat. i'll update my answer.